# How to find rhombus shaped radius in coordinate system? Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, coordinates

I have a map aligned to a coordinate system. Now I want to adjust my `isEmptyWithin(x,y,radius)` function to get a rhombus shaped result instead of square shaped one!

The output I get `(x=6,y=3,radius=1)`:

```
"2,5", "3,5", "4,5", "2,6", "3,6", "4,6", "2,7", "3,7", "4,7"
```

The output I seek `(x=6,y=3,radius=1)`:

```
"3,5", "2,6", "3,6", "4,6", "3,7"
```

The output I get `(x=6,y=3,radius=2)`:

```
"1,4", "2,4", "3,4", "4,4", "5,4", "1,5", "2,5", "3,5", "4,5", "5,5", "1,6", "2,6", "3,6", "4,6", "5,6", "1,7", "2,7", "3,7", "4,7", "5,7", "1,8", "2,8", "3,8", "4,8", "5,8"
```

The output I seek `(x=6,y=3,radius=2)`:

```
"3,4", "2,5", "3,5", "4,5", "1,6", "2,6", "3,6", "4,6", "5,6", "2,7", "3,7", "4,7", "3,8"
```

Here a graphic to show what I seek! Red radius = 1, Blue radius = 2, Pink radius = 3
The Pink and Blue should also include the inner map tiles.
[image: Here a graphic to show what I seek!]

Here my current script which gives me the area on the map as square instead of a rhombus shape:

```
    function isEmptyWithin1(x,y,radius){
    var testXmin = x-radius;
    var testYmin = y-radius;
    var testXmax = x+radius;
    var testYmax = y+radius;
    
    let arr_xy = [];
    
    for (let iy=testYmin;iy<=testYmax;iy++){
        
        for(let ix=testXmin;ix<=testXmax;ix++){
            
            for(let key in map)
            {
                if((map[key]["xy"]==(ix+","+iy))&&(map[key]["type"]!="grass")){
                    map[key]["type"] = "red";
                    arr_xy[arr_xy.length] = ix+","+iy;
                    
                }
            }
        }

        
    }

    if(arr_xy.length==0){
    return false;
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to solve my problem!

First I calculate the diameter from the radius and than I transform the array in rows

```
var int_diameter = 1+(radius*2);
for(var a = 0;a<int_diameter;a++){
    test_arrayROWgen[a] = [];
    test_arrayROWgen[a] = test_array.slice((a*int_diameter),((int_diameter)+(a*int_diameter)));
}
```

Now that I have a new temporary array split into rows.

I simple decrement my given radius as `int_remove` and use it to remove `int_remove` array entrys at the start and the end of each row.

After a row is finished I decrement the `int_remove` and if `int_remove` is ==0 I switch from decrement to increment.
So given the `radius=2` it will delete in the following `5 rows` at the start and end `(2,1,0,1,2)` items/entrys

```
for(var i=0;i<test_arrayROWgen.length;i++){
    
    if(int_remove!=0){
    //remove at end of row
    test_arrayROWgen[i].splice(test_arrayROWgen[i].length-int_remove,int_remove);
    //remove at start of row
    test_arrayROWgen[i].splice(0,int_remove);
    }
    int_remove = int_remove+int_sign;
    
    if(int_remove==0){
        int_sign = 1;
    }
    
}
```

And at the End I got a result like this in my prototype:
[image: And at the End I got a result like this in my prototype]